# angular.copy() doesn't work in setTimeout()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have find example of get data like this :

```
$http.get("/js/data/movies.json")
        .then(function(results){
            //Success
            angular.copy(results.data, _movies); //this is the preferred; instead of $scope.movies = result.data
        }, function(results){
            //Error
        })
```

This updates data when request is done and request to server delay some time, so i have replace $http request with timeout but it doesn't work, no update of data.

```
setTimeout(function(){
        angular.copy({text : 'test'}, _data);//it doesn't update my layout
    }, 100);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular is not aware of the updates that take place inside setTimeout. So you need to reapply the scope to notify Angular of the changes:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $scope.$apply(function(){
        angular.copy({text : 'test'}, _data);
    });
}, 100);
```

Ideally you should use Angular's $timeout to get rid of that $scope.$apply()

```
$timeout(function(){
    angular.copy({text : 'test'}, _data);
},100);
```

Comment: Thanks it has work, but why it doesn't work with setTimeout()?